# R 3.2.3 new H2o Package (2015) cannot achieve the same results from old package

Tags: r, h2o

I was using H2o R package (2014 version) to perform a deep learning task using textual data. I did my research in early 2015 and obtained promising results using deep learning method (function - h2o.deeplearning; e.g. fscore and recall always achieve >0.9). I found that my original R code doesn't work now (due to the change of H2o package in Nov 2015) and i revised my code. However, when i tried to run the same deep learning model (same setting), I could not achieve an outperfom results anymore!! please, I wish to know if H2o has changed any internal modeling settings since the revision of the H2o package? I wish to reproduce my old results with the new package... please kindly help.

Comment: Have you pinged the H2O folks, I suspect they will be responsive ?

Answer (score 0):

H2O Deep Learning (2.0 and 3.0) is not reproducible by default -- you can change this by setting `reproducible = TRUE`, however that will slow things down quite a bit, as reproducibility requires the code to be run on a single core.  Therefore the variability could be due to the randomness in the algorithm alone, rather than from the upgrade of H2O 2.0 to 3.0.

If you want to use H2O Classic (2.0), then your old code will still work, as is.  You might try running that first to see if you can track down the source of the variability.  There is nothing wrong with using H2O Classic to finish a project that you started a while ago.

Implementation details for H2O 3.0 Deep Learning are available in the [Deep Learning booklet](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/latest_stable_DeepLearning_booklet.html).

There is more information on what has changed in H2O DL between H2O 2.0 and 3.0 [here](http://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-tibshirani/8/docs-website/h2o-docs/index.html#Porting%20R%20Scripts-Deep%20Learning).

Comment: Thanks Erin, I just wonder how could I still use my old code. It did not work (under the same platform) when i rerun it recently so that i rewrite my code. But I would love to reproduce my old results.

Comment: here is my old function:       
  h2oann <-h2o.deeplearning(x = 2:ncol(data), 
                   y = 1,  
                   data = h2otrain, # data in H2O format
                   activation = "TanhWithDropout", # or 'Tanh'
                   input_dropout_ratio = 0.2, # % of inputs dropout
                   hidden_dropout_ratios = c(0.5,0.5,0.5), 
                   balance_classes = TRUE, 
                   hidden = c(50,50,50), # three layers of 50 nodes
                   epochs = 100)

Comment: All you need is a copy of H2O Classic (2.0), which you can download here: https://s3.amazonaws.com/h2o-release/h2o-classic/master/latest.html  Let me know if you have any trouble getting that installed.  It will be easiest if you uninstall your current h2o R package first.